# How to keep the maximize button without allowing normal resizing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, resize, layout-manager

I have a `JFrame` that works pretty good when it's in its created state or maximized, but not really in-between. I know you can do `frame.setResizable(false)` to keep the frame from being resized, but then it doesn't show the maximize button. Any idea on how I can disable resizing *and* keep the maximize button?

Comment: Your question begs the question of why -- why show a button if it is to have no effect?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Why would it serve no effect? The maximize button would maximize the window as usual.

Comment: Ah, I misread the question then -- sorry

Comment: *"works pretty good when it's in its created state or maximized, but not really in-between"* .. you're (apparently) doing it wrong. 1) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

> works pretty good when it's in its created state or maximized, but not really in-between

Also, agree you may not be using layout managers effectively if your components can't resize smaller. The layout of components on a frame should be also to respond to increases and decreases in frame size.

However, you can control the minimum size of the frame with code like:

```
frame.add(...);
frame.pack();
frame.setMinimumSize( frame.getPreferredSize() );
frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
frame.setVisible( true );
```